# I want my code to not extract links with 0 seeders using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i wrote my code but it extract all links no matter what value is the seeders count,
here is the code i wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

url = input('What site you working on today, sir?\n-> ')

opener = AppURLopener()
html_page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
pd = str(soup.findAll('td', attrs={'align':re.compile('right')}))
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^magnet")}):
    if not('0' is pd[18]):
       print (link.get('href'),'\n')
```

and this is the html am working on : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImjPG.jpg
in this case it's 0 seeders but it still gives me the magnet link.. HELP

Comment: Can you post the code snippet as text or URL from where is the HTML code in your question? That way we can help you faster.

Comment: https://pirateproxy.mx/browse/201/1/3
this one for example, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to extract all the links but you want omit all links where number of seeders is zero?

Comment: yes, all magnet links except the ones with 0 seeders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet will extract all magnet links from the page, where seeders != `0`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://pirateproxy.mx/browse/201/1/3').text, 'lxml')
tds = soup.select('#searchResult td.vertTh ~ td')
links = [name.select_one('a[href^=magnet]')['href'] for name, seeders, leechers in zip(tds[0::3], tds[1::3], tds[2::3]) if seeders.text.strip() != '0']

pprint(links, width=120)
```

Prints:

```
['magnet:?xt=urn:btih:aa8a1f7847a49e640638c02ce851effff38d440f&dn=Affairs.of.State.2018.BRRip.x264.AC3-Manning&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',
 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:819cb9b477462cd61ab6653ebc4a6f4e790589c3&dn=Bad.Samaritan.2018.BRRip.x264.AC3-Manning&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',
 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:843d01992aa81d52be68190ee6a733ec9eee9b13&dn=The+Darkest+Minds+2018+HDCAM-1XBET&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',
 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:09a23daa69c42003d905ecf0a1cefdb0474e7d88&dn=Insidious+The+Last+Key+2018+BRRip+x264+AAC-SSN&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',
 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:98c42d5d620b4db834c5437a75f6da6f2d158207&dn=The+Darkest+Minds+2018+HDCAM-1XBET%5BTGx%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',
 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f30ebc409b215f2a5237433d7508c7ebfabb0e16&dn=Journeyman.2017.SWESUB.BRRiP.x264.mp4&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969',

...and so on.
```

EDIT:

The `soup.select('#searchResult td.vertTh ~ td')` will select all `<td>` siblings of tag `<td>` with class `vertTh` which is inside tag with `id=searchResult`. There are three siblings like this in each row.

The `select_one('a[href^=magnet]')` will then select all links that `href` begins with `magnet`.